# For a permissions interface settings, how to better handle multiple checkboxes on one screen?

Tags: interface, checkboxes

[image]

Is this the best way to display the `checkboxes` in the below screen?

Should I add **Select all** for the `checkboxes`?

Comment: some more context on this would be helpful

Comment: What are your concerns about the checkboxes? Arrangement? Whether you need "Select All" depends on the use cases. Who are your users and what do they need to achieve with this UI? Please do some research and thinking yourself. We're here to help you, not to do your work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With not the full context, this is what I can come up with to support you.

From your UI, I can see that **all your permissions (view, add etc..) are exactly the same across the 7 categories**. Therefore I would suggest a **2x2 grid** which also have a quick select all checkbox too. It would look like this:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

I'm not entirely sure about what this minefield of checkboxes is supposed to accomplish, but some advice *probably* is:

- Most of these checkboxes don't need to be checkboxes. Many of these actions can be buttons instead. For example, "Edit" could be a pencil icon which lets you edit one item at a time.
- Some of these actions don't need to be shown at all times. For example, if a resource hasn't been added yet, viewing or deleting it doesn't make much sense, so these actions don't need to be shown.

> should I add Select all for the checkboxes?

In what situation would be Adding and Deleting a thing at the same time be useful? I don't think "select all" would do anything for usability here.

Comment: I believe these checkboxes are some sort of permissions for pages on the website (my best guess), in that case checkboxes are valid solution. OP should definitely add more context.